# ReactJS - Clear select value on focus

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, select, onfocus

I need to clear the selected value of select dropdown as soon as user focus on the select element. I have used the below code but cant figure out what property of select do I need to reset.

```
<select name="select1" onChange={this.onChangeOption} onFocus={this.handleFocus}>
    <option value=''>Please select...</option>
    <option value='A'>A</option>
    <option value='B'>B</option>
    <option value='C'>C</option>
    <option value='D'>D</option>
</select>

handleFocus(event) {
    event.target.select(); // it did not work!!
}
```

I want the selected value to be `Please select...` when the user focuses on the element.

Comment: So basically, you want the selected value to be `Please select...` when the user focuses on the element?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the problems with your select element is that it's neither a controlled or an uncontrolled input element. What you want to achieve can be done with both methods, and it looks like you attempted to make a controlled component.

I'll provide a solution for both:

---

### Clearing a *controlled* `<select>` element

You need to turn your select element into a controlled component by assigning it a value which is controlled by the state. Then, make your `handleFocus` function reset that state variable.

For example:

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {select: ''};
  }
  
  onChangeOption = (event) => {
    this.setState({select: event.target.value});
  }
  
  handleFocus = (event) => {
    this.setState({select: ''});
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <select name="select1" value={this.state.select} onChange={this.onChangeOption} onFocus={this.handleFocus}>
        <option value=''>Please select...</option>
        <option value='A'>A</option>
        <option value='B'>B</option>
        <option value='C'>C</option>
        <option value='D'>D</option>
    </select>
    );
  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

---

### Clearing an *uncontrolled* `<select>` element

If you want to let the DOM manage the select element you could do the following to clear the value whenever the `focus` event is fired.

```js
class MyApp extends React.Component {
  
  handleFocus = (event) => {
    event.target.value = '';
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <select name="select1" onFocus={this.handleFocus}>
        <option value=''>Please select...</option>
        <option value='A'>A</option>
        <option value='B'>B</option>
        <option value='C'>C</option>
        <option value='D'>D</option>
    </select>
    );
  }
}
 
ReactDOM.render(<MyApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply!! However I ran your snippet and noticed that the resEt works inconsistently when you focus after selecting a value. You select 'A' then focus on the dropdown here the reset does not work. you focus again the reset will work!

Comment: @Manu, for me it works as expected. Remember that the reset function will only happen on the **focus** event. Focus only happens when the element **gets** focused and didn't have it before. In other words, you need to "click away" and unfocus the element and re-focus it.

Comment: If this isn't the behavior you want, perhaps you want to use `onMouseDown` instead? Here is the exact same snippet as above, but listening on the mouse down event instead: https://jsfiddle.net/877xpvwf/

Comment: I tried onSelect and in handler set event.target.value=''; but it did not work!

Comment: onMouseDown is what did the trick for me. Just for my knowledge wanted to know if onSelect does not work in React?

Comment: @Manu, it was my mistake suggesting onSelect. It is only defined for input and textarea elements.